# Why do my spells toss enemies around, and how can I prevent that?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is it normal that my spells (like Fireball or Flash), at level adept, toss the enemies around like hell? If I fire one of those spells on them the enemies will be thrown like 10 meters away. It looks weird and also makes looting sometimes kind of hard. Now I wonder if this is normal or if one of the mods I installed is responsible for this. All mods I've installed are just for graphical purposes, though, like textures and stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Skyrim physics are funky that way. If you want a more sensible experience, the [Realistic Ragdoll and Force mod](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=601) is what you are looking for.

> Reduces the extra force applied on ragdolls to a more realistic level and replaces ragdolls so that they are no longer stiff and fall at a faster velocity.

Comment: Okay tried it and does totally fix it! Thank you!!!